# Abilities of the Enterprise of the future

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the episode [All Good Things](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/All_Good_Things..._%28episode%29) the Enterprise (of the future) has cloaking abilities and can travel at least Warp 13 and has 3 warp nacelles.

Is there anything else known about this ship?  Is there any resource showing more about it's stats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some more info is on Memory Alpha [here](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_%28NCC-1701-D%29#Anti-time_eruption), not too much extra detail:

> In this alternate future, the Enterprise had undergone several significant modifications, including the addition of a third nacelle, a cloaking device, and a powerful phaser mounted underneath the saucer section. She single-handedly destroyed one Klingon battleship with 8 shots from this phaser. The first hit and two others went straight through both the enemy shields and hull...
>
> This version is referred to in the PC Game Birth of the Federation as the **Galaxy X-class heavy cruiser.** It is armed with phaser arrays and quantum torpedoes.
>
> The Playmates toy of the alternate future Enterprise was described as a ship capable of Transwarp velocities.

---

Also, Galaxy-X has a [Memory Beta page](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Galaxy_X_class), with some minor extra details:

```
Dimensions
 Length:     641 meters
 Width:      467.1 meters

Specifications
 Decks:      42
 Defences:  deflector shields

The additional engine nacelle assembly greatly increased the ship's speed and power.
```

Extra sources: TNG video game: Birth of the Federation; STO video game: Star Trek Online; CCG set: Alternate Universe, card: "Future Enterprise".

Comment: Funny that Memory-Beta says the extra nacelle would increase speed _and power_, as the warp core/matter-antimatter reactor is what generates the power.

Comment: Just think how fast it would go if they rubbed cheetah blood on the engine.